# How to update d3 chart with angular

Tags: angularjs, d3.js

I'm trying to update a D3.js-chart's width in angular using Mike Bostock's [Towards reusable charts](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/chart/?utm_source=feedly) approach. It throws NaNs though and I'm not sure why.

```
// Rag chart
.directive( 'ragChart', [
function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            data: '=',
            id: '=',
            width: '=',
            height: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element) {

            // Default bottom color
            var bottomColor = 'green';
            var height = scope.height;

            // Create canvas
            var parent = d3.select(element[0]);

            // Render graph
            var render = function(data, width, height) {

                console.log(height);
                console.log(width);

                var svg = parent.append('svg:svg')
                .attr('class', 'rag')
                .attr('width', scope.width)
                .attr('height', height);

                var svgG = svg.append('svg:g')
                .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')');

                // Width of charts
                var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, width]);

                // Height of chart
                var y = d3.scale.linear().range([0, height]);

                // Color of charts
                if (bottomColor == 'red'){
                    var color = d3.scale.ordinal().range(['rag-red', 'rag-amber', 'rag-green']);
                }
                else {
                    var color = d3.scale.ordinal().range(['rag-green', 'rag-amber', 'rag-red']);
                }

                // Stack data together
                var remapped =['green-data', 'amber-data', 'red-data']
                    .map(function(dat,i){
                        return data.map(function(d,ii){
                            return {x: ii, y: d[i+1] };
                        });
                    });

                // Use stacked layout
                var stacked = d3.layout.stack()(remapped);

                // Scale charts on axes
                x.domain(stacked[0].map(function(d) {return d.x;}));
                y.domain([0, d3.max(stacked[stacked.length - 1], function(d) { return d.y0 + d.y; })]);

                // Group if multiple charts/bars in order to color
                var valgroup = svgG.selectAll('g.valgroup')
                    .data(stacked)
                    .enter().append('svg:g')
                    .attr('class', 'valgroup')
                    .attr('class', function(d, i){ return color(i);});

                // Draw bars
                var rect = valgroup.selectAll('rect')
                    .data(function(d){return d;})
                    .enter().append('svg:rect')
                    .attr('x', function(d) { return x(d.x); })
                    .attr('y', function(d) { return -y(d.y0) - y(d.y); })
                    .attr('width', x.rangeBand())
                    .attr('height', function(d) { return y(d.y); })

            };

            render.height = function(data) {
                if(!arguments.length) return height;
                height = parseInt(data);
                //duration = 0;
                console.log(this);
                return this;
            };

            render(scope.data, scope.width, scope.height);


            // Watch for data-, width- or height changes and render charts new in case an update occurs
            // Use true for 'objectEquality' property so comparisons are done on equality and not reference
            scope.$watch('data', function(){
                //render(scope.data, scope.width, scope.height);
            }, true);

            scope.$watch('width', function(){
                console.log('test');
                parent.call(render.height(scope.height));
                //scope.render(scope.data, scope.width, scope.height);
            }, true);

            scope.$watch('height', function(){
                //scope.render(scope.data, scope.width, scope.height);
            }, true);
        }
    };
}
]);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vbdbbhur/

It should change it's width when clicking the button, but apparently doesn't.

I also found [this](http://bl.ocks.org/biovisualize/5372077) pretty useful example that actually does pretty much what I'd like to achieve, but unfortunately don't understand how to implement that in my code.

Can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: I suggest you start for example with this [tutorial](http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/d3-on-angular.html) on using D3 and AngularJS to get your head around the basics.

Comment: It's a lot clearer to me now, will see if I can figure it out with that, but I'm confident. Thank you!

Comment: Article posted by @muenchdo is now can be accessed [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150627142524/http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/d3-on-angular.html)